# ImageButton in EditText

Tags: android-imagebutton, edittextpreference

What is the code to make an **image button** to stay at the top right of an **EditText** even when scrolled instead of following data input causing a messy appearance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a custom component, extending `RelativeLayout` and then apply a custom layout.

Have a look at this article, you can get the desired result with just few edit of this code:
https://arunbadole1209.wordpress.com/2011/12/16/how-to-create-edittext-with-crossx-button-at-end-of-it/

clearable_edit_text.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/clearable_edit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="35dip"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clearable_button_clear"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/image_clear"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

ClearableEditText.java

```
public class ClearableEditText extends RelativeLayout
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    EditText edit_text;
    ImageButton btn_clear;
    public ClearableEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        initViews();
    }
    public ClearableEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        initViews();
    }
    public ClearableEditText(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        initViews();
    }
    void initViews()
    {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.clearable_edit_text, this, true);
        edit_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.clearable_edit);
        btn_clear = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.clearable_button_clear);
        btn_clear.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);
        clearText();
        showHideClearButton();
    }
    void clearText()
    {
        btn_clear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
                edit_text.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
    void showHideClearButton()
    {
        edit_text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (s.length() > 0)
                    btn_clear.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
                else
                    btn_clear.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }
    public Editable getText()
    {
        Editable text = edit_text.getText();
        return text;
    }
}
```

To use it, declaration:

```
<com.yourpackage.ClearableEditText
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```